# My site works fine in FF, but IE7 gives me error

Tags: php, jquery

Here is my site:
http://www.sumsy.com/temp/templatesys/config.php?template=1

IE6, 7 give me errors.

Line 9
Char 3
Expected identifier, string or number
Code 0
URL: config.php?template=1

so for situation like this, how do you guys debug it?
I dont even know the error is coming from JS code or Php code.
IE doesnt say which file.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a#changeTemplate").fancybox(
            {
                'autoDimensions'    : false,
            'width'                 : 350,
            'height'                : 'auto', // here

        }
);
```

try removing the extra comma on `auto,` in custom.js
[image]

[source](http://amix.dk/blog/post/19388)

Comment: great one! fixed now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Shadow As you can see, IE does tell you which file.

Comment: As an aside, when you pass an associative array "{a: aval, b:bval}" you do not need to enclose the name in quotes. So instead of "'width': 350, 'height': 'auto'", you should code "width: 350, height: 'auto'".

Comment: @Neil *"When you pass an object literal, ..."* is the correct JavaScript terminology.

Comment: @Shadow_boi - if the answer has sorted the problem for you, please mark it as "Accepted" (click the tick icon next to the answer). Thank you :)

Comment: @Neil: I know it's not required to use quotes, but isn't it "proper" to use quotes? At least JSON says to use quotes.